# Can I replace Windows Vista that is on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, windows-vista

I have an older Toshiba laptop running Vista Home version...  It is sluggish to say the least.  I would like to use it solely to get on the internet for research and thought that I good utilization would be to replace the OS with Ubuntu.  I see how many people have done this with Ubuntu 12 but the only version that I found available was 16.04...  so wanted to know if I could do the same thing with this version.

Also, does Ubuntu support the wireless G card that is in the laptop or will I need to use a cable connection once I get the installation done?  I can connect to the internet while I am doing the installation, but I would like to move the laptop to a location that does not have a cable ability once it is completed.

I will not be needing the computer for any audio or printing...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: please be more specific about your hardware, and someone may be able to answer ;)

Comment: Most likely, 16.04 should work and everything should go fine.

Comment: It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

you could do a temporary boot from a USB and see how you get on.I have installed Ubuntu on 5 computers and it was worked every time. One laptops wifi did not work with Windows but worked fine with Ubuntu. I would use the previous LTS - precise pangolin as 16.04 is a bit too new. I suggest you go to [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) download an image to a usb and give it a try. Also for Printing Ubuntu is usually plug and play unless you are getting into wireless printing. If your laptop is old and lacks memory you could try Lubuntu or Peppermint; both are based on Ubuntu but are made lite to help with the capabilities of older machines.

Give it a go - I did and I never looked back to Windows.

Distro available at Unetbootin;

```
Ubuntu
Kubuntu
Xubuntu
Lubuntu
Debian
openSUSE
Arch Linux
Damn Small Linux
SliTaz

Linux Mint
Zenwalk
Slax
Dreamlinux
Elive
CentOS
Mandriva
FreeBSD
NetBSD

Fedora
PCLinuxOS
Sabayon Linux
Gentoo
MEPIS
LinuxConsole
Frugalware Linux
xPUD
Puppy Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about the laptop anyway I would advise just going for it. installing and see what happens. It's the best way to learn to be honest. (If you are aiming to learn a bit more about Ubuntu)